# A plugin like "Resharper" for SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: plugins, ssms

Does anybody know of a program or plugin for SQL Server Management Studio which is like Resharper for MS Visual Studio?

For example, it would be great to enter Ctrl-Shift-N and after starting to enter the name of a stored procedure to see list of stored procedures with most general commands like - alter, drop and create.

Comment: Context aware hints would be nice too like "Hey you started a TRAN but did not COMMIT in any execution path"

Answer (score 17):

Look at the ApexSQL refactor, it is FREE amazing add-in for Visual Studio and SQL Management Studio. http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx

Answer (score 9):

You can try [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) by redgate

Answer (score 7):

I came across another interesting plugin called [SqlSmash](http://www.sqlsmash.com/). It works with SSMS 2012 and is free for now it looks like.

Features from the website:

> - Go To Object: Easily navigate to any of the tables, stored procedures, functions or triggers in any of your databases.
> - Format Sql: Apply your casing preferences to the keywords, variables and identifiers and indent the Sql.
> - Execute Current Query: Only execute the query that your cursor is placed at.
> - Search Objects: Search all your database objects for any text.
> - Summarize Script: Summarize complex scripts and navigate around easily.
> - Go To Definition: Show the definition of a Sql object quickly.
> - Find All References: Find what other objects are referencing the Sql Object under your cursor.
> - Quick Info: Get a quick overview about the Sql Object under your cursor.

Comment: Free for 30 days only, sadly.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it has that autocomplete feature you've mentioned (which is in MS Management Studio >= 2008) but the "SSMS Tools Pack" add-in has some other features you might be interested in:
http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/

Features:

- SQL Snippets
- Window Connection Coloring
- Window Content History, Query Execution History and Current Window History
- Format SQL
- Search Table, View or Database Data
- Run one script on multiple databases
- Copy execution plan bitmaps to clipboard or file
- Search Results in Grid Mode
- Generate Insert statements from resultsets, tables or database
- Regions and Debug sections
- Running custom scripts from Object Explorer
- CRUD stored procedure generation
- New query template
- General options

Comment: still free if you are using < 2012 otherwise there is a license cost =( unfortunate that its no longer a community project